# Using transactions when combining a RepositoryRestResource with another repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-transactions

I have a simple `JpaRepository` annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, UUID> { }
```

Whenever something is changed in the database, I want to update a file. I do this using a `RepositoryEventHandler`:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class ItemRepositoryEventHandler {

    @HandleAfterCreate
    @HandleAfterSave
    @HandleAfterDelete
    public void itemChanged(Item item) {
        writeToFile();
    }
}
```

**What I want to do is if there is an error while writing the contents to file, then the database should be rolled back.**

I've tried by adding the `@Transactional` annotation to the `ItemRepository` but it didn't work. Debugging revealed that the `RepositoryRestResource` does three steps: emitting the `BeforeXXX` events, persisting to the database, then emitting the `AfterXXX` events. It only uses a transaction during the persistence step, not one across all three.

So I see no way to use a transaction across the whole operation and the only alternative I see is to not use `@RepositoryRestResource`, but to implement the web layer manually then use a service which employs a transaction across both repositories. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to implement your business logic with a custom controller and a service. But this way is neutralizing the 'advantages' of Spring Data REST.

Another option (in my opinion it's more natural for SDR) is to use [published events from aggregate roots](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.domain-events). In this case you should extend your entities from [AbstractAggregateRoot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractAggregateRoot.html) and implement a method that will be publish some 'event'. Then you will be able to handle this event (with help of `@EventListener`) in the same transaction during the process of saving your entity. For example:

```java
@Entity
public class Order extends AbstractAggregateRoot {
    //...

    public void registerItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.registerEvent(new RegisterItemsEvent(this, items));
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegisterItemsEvent {
    private final Order order;
    private final List<Item> items;
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class EventHandler {

    private final ItemRepo itemRepo;

    @EventListener
    @Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY)
    public void handleRegisterItemsEvent(RegisterItemsEvent e) {
        Order order = e.getOrder();
        List<Item> items = e.getItems();

        // update items with order - skipped...

        itemRepo.saveAll(items);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```java
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class OrderEventHandler {

    @BeforeCreate
    public void handleOrderCreate(Order order) {

        // prepare a List of items - skipped...

        order.registerItems(items);        
    }
}
```

When SDR saves the `Order` then it emits `RegisterItemsEvent`, which is handled in `handleRegisterItemsEvent` method of your `EventHandler` that saves prepared items in the same transaction (we use `propagation = MANDATORY` parameter of `@Transaction` annotation to make sure that transaction is present).

Additional info: [Domain event publication from aggregate roots](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/30/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-ingalls#domain-event-publication-from-aggregate-roots)

**UPDATED**

Regarding your particular task, you can create class `ItemChangedEvent`:

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemChangedEvent {
    private final Item item;
}
```

Implement method `markAsChanged` in the `Item` entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Item extends AbstractAggregateRoot {
    //...

    public void markAsChanged() {
        this.registerEvent(new ItemChangedEvent(this));
    }
}
```

When the `item` changes, you will mark it as "changed":

```java
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class ItemRepositoryEventHandler {

    @BeforeCreate
    @BeforeSave
    @BeforeDelete
    public void itemChanged(Item item) {
        item.markAsChanged();
    }
}
```

And write it to a file in the `ItemChangedEvent` handler in the same transaction:

```java
@Component
public class EventHandler {

    @EventListener
    @Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY)
    public void handleItemChangedEvent(ItemChangedEvent e) {
        Item item = e.getItem();
        writeToFile(item);
    }
}
```